# Facebook - Get Last Status Updates From Feed

Tags: c#, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given a facebook username and password, how do I grab the latest status updates from his feed? Moreover, i'd like to know how to get last updates from user profile.
I'm having trouble finding an answer to this question, and I'd like to know whether it could by done using PHP or C# (C# is prefrred). I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution, thanks in advance !

Comment: Facebook has an API which expects requests. You can send requests from any languages, provided that you have a connection to the internet on the machine where you are running your request. Read the Facebook API documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by using the Facebook Graph API in any language. I suggest you should look at the API documentation, specifically the [User Reference Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) (you can retrieve any user's status updates using this). It might take some time to understand how it all work, but you can retrieve user information very easily, provided you have the knowledge of a specific language and you understand how the Graph API actually works (there are plenty of example on the developers' website).

Also, you don't even require user's password for this. All you need is the user's id or username and some permissions from that user (or simply an [Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)).

PS: If you have any specific problem in your code, please update your question with some code that you've written till now and I'll be happy to help you with that.

Comment: first of all , thanks for the answer. I'd like to know how it could be done without using the user's password, since I might send a request with user's id, but the user's wall might be private. another explanation would be great, if possible of course. thanks again

Comment: As I said, you require extra permissions along with the username or user id. This whole thing combined is called an Access Token. If you have this Access Token (i.e. user has allowed you or your app to access his statuses), then you can retrieve his recent status using graph API.